# Buscar coincidencia en propiedad de objeto en array

Tags: javascript

Alguno ve qué está mal con esta función? Se supone que debe encontrar coincidencia entre esos dos id y devolver la posición en "arrayStock" para luego pushear ese objeto a "arrayCarrito"

```
function agregar(event){
    for(let i=0; i<arrayStock.length; i++){
        if(arrayStock[i].id==event.target.parentElement.id){
            return i;
            break;
        }
        return;
    }
    arrayCarrito.push(arrayStock[i]);
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! solamente estas comprobando un elemento... pone un par de comentarios a tu codigo y te vas a dar cuenta

Comment: Todo lo que escribas después de una sentencia `return` será ignorado. Por lo tanto esa sentencia `break` no se hará. Además si en la primera iteración no entra en el condicional, se ejecutará la sentencia `return` finalizando la ejecución de la función. Todo está mal, incluso la palabra *pushear* que no existe en castellano. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Código con correciones.

```
function agregar(event) {
      // crear una variable para guardar el índice del elemento
      // si se encuentra
      let indice = -1;
    
      for (let i = 0; i < arrayStock.length; i++) {
        if (arrayStock[i].id == event.target.parentElement.id) {
          // si se encuentra, guardar el índice y terminar
          indice = i;
          break;
          // el return hace que la función finalice
          // return i
        }
        // el return hace que la función finalice
        //return;
      }
      // si el índice es mayor o igual a cero
      // significa que se encontró el producto
      if (indice >= 0) arrayCarrito.push(arrayStock[indice]);
    }
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, funcionó!